# tags for foreign key gorm with references to main table

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

There is main table:
Users

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
        id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
```

There is a subordinate table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_history:
...
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) 
  REFERENCES users(id)  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

How define gorm tags for foreign key and references, with constraints on update on delete?

I understand only (possible, with errors):

```
    UserID    uint64    `gorm:"column:user_id; type: bigint; gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs on HasMany relationships and foreign key constraints](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#FOREIGN-KEY-Constraints) should help you.

- Create a `UserHistory` struct with a foreign key field `UserID`, no tags needed on this.

  - Because of the way you have named your table, you'll need to add a `TableName() string` function to this model that returns `"users_history"` (by default gorm would use `user_histories` otherwise)
- Create a `User` struct with an `ID` field

  - Add a `[]UserHistory` field in this struct and name it something reasonable like `History`. This is where the constraint tags go `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`

That's it.